# RAID 1 Disks are Both Blank

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, raid, raspberrypi, mdadm

I have Ubuntu Server running on a Raspberry Pi 4 with 2 2TB hard disks that were in a RAID 1 array. After powering down the server to move some cables and replace one of the adapters, my RAID array has completely disappeared from CockPit. If I plug either drive into the Pi or any other machine, with any adapter, both drives just show a blank partition table now. Running `sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdc` shows the following:

`/dev/sdc: MBR Magic : aa55 Partition[0] :    488378645 sectors at            1 (type ee)`

How should a RAID disk partition table look? How should I continue to recover my data and the array? Any help is deeply appreciated, I think I'm in a little over my head here.

EDIT: I found this answer over at Unix SE:https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598504
The accepted answer says to recreate the RAID in the same way, and links to yet another answer talking about the mdadm command used. I gather the idea there is to just recreate the RAID info and it should then find the data on the drive. I created this array in CockPit, is it safe to plug both drives in and just recreate the array from CockPit the same way I did originally?

Comment: as its usb devices, consider that devices reference may change ie `/dev/sdc` may become `/dev/sdd`. So mdadm may be lost, you'll have to review his config file.

Comment: My drives are being mounted as sdb and sdc, my /etc/mdadm/mdadm.config only has two commands: 'HOMEHOST <system>' and 'MAILADDR root'

Comment: please [edit] the question to copy/paste the output of `sudo mdadm --query --detail /dev/md* `